# Android: getting details of an item selected in an autocomplete text view

Tags: android

I am trying to parse a json onto my autocomplete text view.

**This is my sample json response.**

```
{
"Result":{
"status":"success",
"Data":[
{
"id":"ABW",
"name":"Abber Wilson",
"unicode":"ABWN",
"latitude":"51.716154",
"longitude":"-3.451816"
},
{
"id":"SHM",
"name":"Shawn Michels",
"unicode":" SHMJR",
"latitude":"54.797134",
"longitude":"-4.411612"
},
{
"id":"JHA",
"name":"Jhon Abraham",
"unicode":" JHAM ",
"latitude":"58.116014",
"longitude":"-5.151016"
},
```

So on autocomplete textview on a page i am showing the name and to the next page i am supposed to pass the unicode of the corresponding name selected in the autocomplete textview.

```
actvfrom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String str = s.toString();
        if (str.equals(" ")) {
            actvfrom.setText("");
        }
        if (str.length() > 0 && actvfrom.hasFocus()) {
            // actvfrom.setThreshold(1);
            actvfrom.setAdapter(commonAdapter);
            deletefrom.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_delete1);
        } else {
            deletefrom.setImageResource(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
    { }

    //autocomplete text view after 3 characters

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String s1 = s.toString();
        actvfrom.setSelection(s1.length());
        if (NameList.contains(s1)) {
            actvfrom.setDropDownHeight(0);
            //actvfrom.setDropDownHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        } else {
            actvfrom.setDropDownHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // actvfrom.setDropDownHeight(0);
        }
    }
}
```

the above code shows the autocomplete textview.

Answer (score 0):

Put your source in ArrayList<> ,get selected item position and then you can extract the values which you wanna send to next activity.